# RoR Gems for Gamification , Friends , Account , News Feeds etc

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

Hi I am really new in RoR and now working with my personal pet project , Now I am Trying to get some of these gems if there are any available and if they are up to date and still being supported that would realy help me loads.

Gamification Gems - something that has leader boards , leveling etc.

Facebook like gems - User Accounts , News feeds , Friends.

Quest gems.

Email Generator gems .

facebook loging and other social media login gems

Anything in there would really help me!  Already using rails_admin as a back end solution and ck_editor for the editing stuff and some other gems that i am currently using.

anything really helps in this point and I am very willing to learn a bit more also for my studies!

And thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

There's a site made just for you: https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/ well at least made for answer the same questions.